# How do I access a Cascading Parameter of a Layout component for the NotFound case

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm currently learning Blazor Web App in .NET 8.

I'm aware that NotFound is no longer used in Blazor Web Apps.

However, I was practicing how to use Cascading Parameters between the Layout components I've made and the pages that use these layouts.

I have two layouts, AuthenticatedLayout and AnonymousLayout. When a page is found, my route defines the page to render on the AuthenticatedLayout:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(AuthenticatedLayout)" />
    <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
</Found>
```

In Program.cs, I have the following line to force redirect when I have a 404 error:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/StatusCode/{0}");
```

In my 404 component, since I can't use the NotFound template, I specify the AnonymousLayout with an @layout AnonymousLayout at the top. Here is what the 404 component looks like:

```
@layout AnonymousLayout
@using App.Components.Layout
@page "/StatusCode/404"

<h3>Not Found</h3>

<p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public AnonymousLayout Layout { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Layout._titleText = "404 Error";
    }
}
```

This should interact with my AnonymousLayout Cascading Parameter code:

```
// Cascading Parameters
private string title;
public string _titleText
{
    get => title;
    set
    {
        if (title == value)
            return;
        title = value;
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try to run my application, I get a System.NullReferenceException, with my Layout parameter being considered null.

Following this same pattern with my AuthenticatedLayout layout works fine. I imagine it is because my route component clearly specifies the Layout to be used but in the case of NotFound, how do I access this?

Is there anything that I am missing on how to specify the layout for this page?

Comment: Is there any code you are using `<CascadingValue />`?

Comment: ugh.... I guess I should have reviewed my AnonymousLayout component. You're right @QiangFu, I did not put a <CascadingValue /> tag in my anonymouslayout like I did in my AuthenticatedLayout. Once I did this, it finally worked. Thank you very much!